# Select options not showing up

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating an app where page content is changed and replaced dynamically via AJAX (and hashchange jquery script). For some reason within the dynamically changed AJAX content, the select form options are not showing up. Example here:

http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/#enter.php

However, if I run the page, without loading/changing the content via AJAX (remove the # mark in the URL), the select form element works as it is should.

http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/enter.php

This is killing me!!! Please help. Never run into an issue like this before. Don't even know where to start. But here's the dynamic script which I assume is the problem. Can't find any conflicts with the select box though. What gives?

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#appContent"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el; 

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    }); 
    $("#buttonWrap").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });  

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){    
    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);        
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .slideToggle(500, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.slideToggle(500, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");

                    //RE-FIRE OTHER SCRIPTS ON AJAX CONTENT LOAD

                    //Phone Field Format
                    $(function() { 
                        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999",{placeholder:" "});
                    });

                });
            });
    };                         
});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

});

Comment: Ha, no yelling buddy, and if I was it'd be at myself. Not the people I'm asking for help from. :)

Comment: This is just a wild guess at the moment, but could it be that your page is being interpreted as plain HTML by the server rather then PHP as it should?  Having the .php extension in the hash part of the url won't trigger it to be interpreted by the server as php.  Perhaps if what you are using as the homepage is an HTML file, you could change it to be a PHP file instead.

Comment: That did cross my mind, but the homepage I'm using this, which is php as well:
http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/#index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response from the server looks exactly right, but your select element is all mangled after DOM insertion. My guess is that load() + parse-selector is the culprit. Try it with `$.ajax`, something like this:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#appContent"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
    $("#buttonWrap").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .slideToggle(500, function() {
                $mainContent.hide();
                $.ajax({
                    url: newHash,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $mainContent.html($(data).find('#appContent').html());
                        $mainContent.slideToggle(500, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");

                        //RE-FIRE OTHER SCRIPTS ON AJAX CONTENT LOAD

                        //Phone Field Format
                        $(function() {
                            $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999",{placeholder:" "});
                       });
                    }
                });
            });
    }
});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

**EDIT**: full code answer

Comment: Hmm, your code is not working. But I could have implemented it wrong. Plus I'm not using jQuery 1.7. Can you give an example of the regular success callback you mention? Full script?

Comment: I also see that `select` comes back from the server via ajax/load with a self-closing tag: `<select class='select' .../>`. This is no doubt the problem. Editing the answer to explicitly ask for html to see if that helps.

Comment: Appreciate the help. But it doesn't seem to have fixed it...
Not sure what's causing the problem.

Comment: This works for me now: http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/#enter.php

Comment: Certainly does!Looks like it was the self-closing tag error that messed it up. Agh. I always check the source first when troubleshooting. One of those days I suppose. You rock man. Thanks!